# ramotion expanding collection instructions unclear

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to use the expanding-collection library and I'm having some trouble understanding the guide. Here's the readme: https://github.com/Ramotion/expanding-collection/blob/master/README.md

I'm having trouble understanding the first instruction

> Create UICollectionViewCell inherit from BasePageCollectionCell
>   (recommend create cell with xib file)

Does this mean I should add a `collectionviewcell` to `main.storyboard`? As I have tried, however, xCode did not allow me to drag and drop an individual `uicollectionviewcell` into the storyboard or create a class called `UICollectionViewCell` that inherits from `BasePageCollectionCell`.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a new file to add in your project, go File>New>File...>Cocoa Touch Class, enter name of class, select to inherit from BasePageCollectionCell and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

do `File -> New -> File -> View` this will create an XIB file. From there you can delete the view that shows up in the GUI. Then you can drag a `UICollectionViewCell` into it and do what you need to do from there. Although I also recommend looking up how to create a custom XIB for views

Something like this could help you out

https://medium.com/@brianclouser/swift-3-creating-a-custom-view-from-a-xib-ecdfe5b3a960